# concat followed by save in Mongoose does nothing

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose 4.9.1 and MongoDB 2.2.33. I use concat since push is no longer supported, to add an element to an array of a model.
I do save, everything works but the updated object does not have the element I added to the array.

```
hotel.reviews.concat([{
        name : req.body.name,
        rating : parseInt(req.body.rating, 10),
        review : req.body.review
    }]);

    hotel.save(function(err, hotelUpdated) {
       if (err) {
           console.log("Error adding review");
           res
               .status(500)
               .json(err);
       } else {
           res
               .status(201)
               .json(hotelUpdated);
           //.reviews[hotelUpdated.reviews.length - 1]
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried :

```
const item =  {
        name : req.body.name,
        rating : parseInt(req.body.rating, 10),
        review : req.body.review
    };


HotelModel.
findOneAndUpdate({ _id : hotel._id}, {$push:{reviews:item},{new : true},(err, doc) => {

    if(err){
        console.log("Something wrong when updating data!");
    }

    console.log(doc);
});
```

Comment: In WebStorm the above code does not compile. The curly brace before "new" is an unexpected token. Still a beginner in Javascript so I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: I removed the {new : true} to make it compile, but now it says findOneAndUpdate is not a function, so it must not be supported in the version of Mongoose I'm using, stated above.

Comment: I corrected the code see now . don't forget to change `HotelModel` with the name of your model

Comment: Still an unexpected token: reviews.controllers.js:61
        .findOneAndUpdate({ _id : hotel._id}, {$push:{reviews:item},{new : true},(err, doc) => {
                                                                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)

Comment: What it does not like is the { before new. That's where it puts the caret (^)

Comment: Removing the { new : true } block and closing the push block after it with a } (curly brace) it works! In the edited version of your code there is an unmatched curly brace I think.